# JPA - Attributeconverter not working with native query

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have created AttributeConverter class which is converting Enum to DB value and overriden the necessary methods.
If I use JPA query like below then converter is getting called and getting correct result.

```
public List<Driver> findByStatus(DriverStatus status);
```

BUT If I use with Query annotation that AttributeConverter is not getting called. I have more complex query where I need to use native query with Attribute Converter but it is not working for me.

```
@Query(value = "select * from driver where status=:status", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Driver> findByStatus1(DriverStatus status);
```

is there any way to handle this requirement ?

**Update 1** - below is the Converter code

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class DriverStatusConverter implements AttributeConverter<DriverStatus, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(DriverStatus driverStatus) {
        if (driverStatus == null) {
            return null;
        }
        System.err.println("from converter" +driverStatus.getCode());
        return driverStatus.getCode();
    }

    @Override
    public DriverStatus convertToEntityAttribute(String code) {

        if (code == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return Stream.of(DriverStatus.values()).filter(c -> c.getCode().equals(code)).findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }
}
```

Comment: If possible could you provide the `converter` and `entity` code snippet as well ?

Comment: added the code to question @Sujitmohanty30

Comment: thanks but I would also like you to add the entity as well.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue, wasn't able to find satisfying solution, so had to resort to the ugly hack... Repository method signature was changed like so:

```
public List<Driver> findByStatus1(Integer status);
```

...and was called like so:

```
repository.findByStatus1(DriverStatus.YOUR_DESIRED_STATUS.getCode());
```

Yes, it's ugly and kinda defeats the purpose of AttributeConverter, but at least it works. In my particular case I had to resort to such measures just with one native query. AttributeConverter still works for the all other JPA queries.

Answer (score 0):

I just come across same problem and use following to go around it

`DriverStatusConverter` move logic code in `convertToEntityAttribute` to public static method:

```
@Override
public DriverStatus convertToEntityAttribute(String code) {

    return convertStringToEnum(code);
}

public static DriverStatus convertStringToEnum(String code) {
    if (code == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return Stream.of(DriverStatus.values()).filter(c -> c.getCode().equals(code)).findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
}
```

create new `DriverDTO` for native query result

```
public interface DriverDTO {
    
    public Integer getId();

    public String getName();
    
    public String getStatusCode();

    default DriverStatus getStatus() {
        return DriverStatusConverter.convertStringToEnum(getStatusCode());
    }

}
```

`DriverRepository` findByStatusCode() select columns in query and return `DriverDTO` class

```
@Query(value = "select id, name, status as statusCode from driver WHERE status=:statusCode", nativeQuery = true)
public List<DriverDTO> findByStatusCode(String statusCode);
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove the  `nativeQuery = true` and try.

```
@Query(value = "select * from driver where status=:status")
    public List<Driver> findByStatus1(DriverStatus status);
```

Alternatively you can try using `entityManager` like so -
This is just sample code.

```
TypedQuery<Trip> q = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Trip t WHERE t.vehicle = :v", Trip.class);
q.setParameter("v", Vehicle.PLANE);
List<Trip> trips = q.getResultList();
```

Reference -
https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-21-type-converter-better-way-to/

Comment: The suggested query is not valid JPQL

Comment: Are you talking about the second one? That was just an example of how you can use `entityManager` to create query. I already mentioned in answer that it was just a sample. Basically the idea is i wanted you to try using `entityManager`.

Comment: I'm talking about the first one

Comment: How is that wrong? Here is the reference : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: `select * from driver where status=:status` is a native SQL query. You can't just remove `nativeQuery = true` and expect it to work. In the reference you linked to, the queries for `nativeQuery = true` and `nativeQuery = false` are different

Comment: This one is from JPQL example. Section 6.1
`
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.status = :status and u.name = :name")
User findUserByUserStatusAndUserName(@Param("status") Integer userStatus, 
  @Param("name") String userName);
`

Comment: This one Native one. Section 6.2
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Users u WHERE u.status = :status and u.name = :name", 
  nativeQuery = true)
User findUserByStatusAndNameNamedParamsNative(
  @Param("status") Integer status, @Param("name") String name);

Comment: I don't think there's a difference. Both are right.

Comment: I am afraid you still missed the point. `@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.status = :status and u.name = :name", nativeQuery = false)` is correct. So is `@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Users u WHERE u.status = :status and u.name = :name", nativeQuery = true)`. However, `@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Users u WHERE u.status = :status and u.name = :name", nativeQuery = false)` is wrong, because the query **is a native SQL query** and the annotation is falsely claiming that it's not. This version is what you're suggesting in your answer, because `nativeQuery` defaults to `false`